# Make an ActiveRecord Query based on fields in associated models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following database relation:

```
Entry
has_one :math_test_before, class_name: "MathTest"
has_one :math_test_after, class_name: "MathTest"
```

I want to view every Entry in which `entry.math_test_before.score > entry.math_test_after.score`

How can I make an ActiveRecord query that allows me to refer to each entry's math test scores and compare them?

Comment: Are you open to joins() clauses or do you prefer writing raw sql to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving each object its own database table by using multiple table inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the pastebin](http://pastie.org/private/fatvjjmt8wz9yyfxtht8eq) provided by the OP, the following statement:

```
Entry.joins(:math_test_before, :math_test_after)
     .where('math_test_before.score > math_test_after.score').all
```

produced the following SQL query:

```
Entry Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "math_tests" ON "math_tests"."entry_id" = "entries"."id" INNER JOIN "math_tests" "math_test_afters_entries" ON "math_test_afters_entries"."entry_id" = "entries"."id" WHERE (math_test_before.score > math_test_after.score)
```

Writing the correct statement is now trivial. Here it is:

```
Entry.joins(:math_test_before, :math_test_after)
     .where('math_tests.score > math_test_afters_entries.score').all
```

However, when you run this query, you'll not get the desired results. This is because your associations have not been set up properly. Look at your logs: the math_tests table is joined to the entries table on the same foreign key twice which means that the same test will act as both the before and the after test.

You need to make some changes to your association setup. First of all, your Entry should `belong_to` to two MathTest instances like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :math_test_before, :class_name => 'MathTest'
  belongs_to :math_test_after, :class_name => 'MathTest'
end
```

You will also need to add columns named `math_test_before_id` and `math_test_after_id` to your entries table by creating an appropriate migration and running `rake db:migrate`. After that, edit your MathTest class like this:

```
class MathTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :before_entry, :class_name => 'Entry', :foreign_key => 'math_test_before_id'
  has_one :after_entry, :class_name => 'Entry', :foreign_key => 'math_test_after_id'
end
```

The provided query should work then.

---

**OLDER ATTEMPTS**: The first and second attempts outlined below to write this query failed. They are retained here for the purpose of record so that others don't waste time trying these out.

Something like this should work:

```
Entry.joins(:math_test_before, :math_test_after)
.where('math_test_before.score > math_test_after.score').all
```

Please provide the output of the above statement even if it doesn't give you the desired output. I'm apprehensive only because I've never had the need to use the class_name attribute of the has_one association.

**UPDATE**
Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8588520/563535. As per the poster, the alias name generated is `<assoc_name>_<entity_name_plural>`. So, your query should probably use `math_test_before_entries.score > math_test_after_entries.score`. Getting to look at the generated statement will help us nail this down further.

Comment: In both versions of the query you explicitly suggest, I get the errors listed in this pastie (both with `math_test_before.score` and `math_test_before_entries.score`: http://pastie.org/private/fatvjjmt8wz9yyfxtht8eq.  I also tried to use a modified version of the correct answer in the StackOverflow post you linked to, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax for creating two joins.  My attempt is also in the pastie.

Comment: @EricBaldwin - Somehow I missed you comment until now. Looking at it right now.

Comment: This is a good idea and I appreciate your help.  However, the data model I want has math_tests belonging to entries.